# Programmatically resolve Thymeleaf templates

Tags: spring, templates, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm trying to render XML/JSON using Thymeleaf templates. I don't want to render a view using the template name, just want to resolve the template as shown below. Trouble is all I get back is the template name, not it's content.

**Set up:**

```
@Bean
SpringResourceTemplateResolver xmlTemplateResolver(ApplicationContext appCtx) {
    SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();

    templateResolver.setApplicationContext(appCtx);
    templateResolver.setPrefix("classpath:/templates/");
    templateResolver.setSuffix(".xml");
    templateResolver.setTemplateMode(XML);
    templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding(UTF_8.name());
    templateResolver.setCacheable(false);

    return templateResolver;
}

@Bean
SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine(ApplicationContext appCtx) {
    SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
    templateEngine.addTemplateResolver(xmlTemplateResolver(appCtx));

    return templateEngine;
}
```

**Template (src/main/resources/templates/breakfast-menu.xml):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<breakfast_menu>
    <food>
        <name>${item['name']}</name>
        <price>${item['price']}</price>
        <description>${item['description']}</description>
        <calories>${item['calories']}</calories>
    </food>
</breakfast_menu>
```

**Usage:**

```
@Autowired
SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine;

someMethod() {
    Context context = new Context();
    context.setVariable("item", item);
    item.put("name", "Waffle");
    String content = templateEngine.process("breakfast-menu", context);

    // content == "breakfast-menu". WTH?
}
```

Using Thymeleaf 3.0.0.BETA01.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved this issue with help from the Thymeleaf [user forum](http://web.archive.org/web/20190910071557/http://forum.thymeleaf.org/How-to-Programmatically-resolve-Thymeleaf-templates-td4029441.html). For reasons unbeknownst to me, `templateEngine.addTemplateResolver` doesn't work but `templateEngine.setTemplateResolver` does. The templates for XML and JSON output are shown below:

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<breakfast_menu>
    <food>
        <name th:text="${item['name']}"></name>
        <price th:text="${item['price']}"></price>
        <description th:text="${item['description']}"></description>
        <calories th:text="${item['calories']}"></calories>
    </food>
</breakfast_menu>
```

JSON:

```
{
  "food": {
    "name": "[[${item['name']}]]",
    "price": "[[${item['price']}]]",
    "description": "[[${item['description']}]]",
    "calories": "[[${item['calories']}]]"
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake of completeness is here some code to resolve a Thymeleaf template with plain-Thymeleaf without Spring.
This is for HTML but you can adapt it to some other template mode by setting another parameter for the `setTemplateMode` call:

Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.12.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Java class:

```
import java.util.Map;
import org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine;
import org.thymeleaf.context.Context;
import org.thymeleaf.templatemode.TemplateMode;
import org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.StringTemplateResolver;
public class ThymeleafResolver {
    public static String resolveHTMLWithThymeleaf(String html, Map<String, Object> variables) {
        TemplateEngine templateEngine = new TemplateEngine();
        StringTemplateResolver templateResolver = new StringTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver);
        Context context = new Context();
        context.setVariables(variables);
        return templateEngine.process(html, context);
    }
}
```

Testcase Java code:

```
Map<String, Object> variables = new HashMap<>();
variables.put("mytext", "Hello World");
String result = ThymeleafInterpreter.interpretHTMLWithThymeleaf("<html><body><span th:text=\"${mytext}\"></span></body></html>", variables);
Assert.assertEquals("<html><body><span>Hello World</span></body></html>", result);
```

Comment: The Spring dependency injection has several benefits, like separation of concerns, abstraction and ease of testing. I don’t think putting all the code in one place is a good idea. The code I shown can easily be used without Spring context if you plug in the dependencies yourself., but keeping them separate makes for cleaner code IMO.